# about error recovery from bison2.4.1

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

I want to handle error recovery from bison2.4.1.

I referred to a oreilly's book(lex&yacc) and some websites to put the error token in my rule,

but I think it doesn't work. it doesn't help me handling error recovery!

my code is as follows:

```
PDL:
    DataDesc ComputationDesc    {Build_front_proc($1,$2);}
    ;
DataDesc:
    PartyDecl AccLvDesc     {$$ = echo_dataDesc($1, $2);}
    ;
// Party Description
PartyDecl:
    PARTY ':' ID ',' ID ENDL    {if($3->is_func || $5->is_func)
                        yyerror("it is a reserved word!\n");
                    $$ = echo_partyDecl($3->name,$5->name);}
    |error ENDL         {printf("There is a error");}
    ;
```

I gave words of "Party: id_a ;" (it should be two id name after "Party".)

and it went straight to yyerror() and showed syntax error...

I have no idea why it doesn't handle this error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error handling in YACC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796608/error-handling-in-yacc)

Answer (score 1):

Error rules in yacc/bison don't PREVENT errors -- they RECOVER from errors.  So in this case, you get an error (and it calls `yyerror("syntax error")`), and THEN looks for error rules to recover.  So in this case it will be in a state looking for a `','` to shift, after shifting `PARTY`, `':'`, and `ID`.  In this state, a `';'` can't be parsed, so it will issue a syntax error.  After the error it will start popping states until it finds one with an error production -- in this case 3 states to get to the one that corresponds to the beginning of a `PartyDecl`.  In that state, it will shift the error, putting it in a state expect an `ENDL`.  It will then throw away input symbols (the `;` and anything after it) until it finds an `ENDL`, which it will shift, putting in a state where it can reduce the `PartyDecl: error ENDL` rule, calling `printf("There is a error");`

If it never finds an `ENDL`, it will exit after it gets to an EOF, having never recovered from the error.  In addition, it will remain in error recovery mode for 2 more shifts after the `ENDL` -- if it gets another error before then, it won't call yerror and will instead go directly to error recovery.